# determining which token was matched

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I have a rule that looks like

```
expr : expr op=( PLUS | MINUS ) expr
PLUS : '+'
MINUS : '-'
```

how can I tell which operator was matched? I tried doing `ExprContext.PLUS().getText()` but somehow `ExprContext.PLUS()` returns null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANTLR4 will generate a member `op` for you, so you can do `if (exprContext.op().getText() == "+") ...`.